# Angular UI-Router - Page refresh loses $stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I've used $state.go to pass in an 'employee' object as a parameter to a page where the id is also used as a parameter in the url, but when the page is refreshed, all $stateParams are cleared from the state.

How can I prevent this from happening, and somehow store the data for the employee (as I said, employee id is used in url), so that when the page is refreshed, $stateParams is still populated with this employee's data based upon the id in the url?

**State definition:**

```
 .state('employees/employeeDetails', {
        url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/employees/employeeDetails/employeeDetails.html',
        params: {
            employee: null,
            id: null
        },
        controller: 'employeeDetailsMainController',
        controllerAs: 'employeeDetailsMain',
        resolve: {
            lazyLoad: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/controllers/employees/employeeDetails/employeeDetailsMainController.js');
            }
        }
    })
```

**Directive with `$state.go:`**

```
app.directive('viewEmployee', function() {

var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        employee: '=',
        state: '@state'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.goToEmployee = function() {
            $state.go('employees/employeeDetails', { employee: $scope.employee, id: $scope.employee.id });
        }
    },
    bindToController: {
        employee: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('button').bind('click', function(index, employee) {
            scope.goToEmployee();
        })
    }
}
return directive;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in the route definition another item called :employee

```
    url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:id/:employee'
```

But since employee is an object - so unless you wanna define each item as a param in the url or do a lookup based on the id when you get to the state of the employee itself from the backend... you have other options.

1. use a service to store the employee info
2. localStorage

UPDATE:

So based on what it seems the only genuine option should be to make a backend query to fetch the employee info based on the ID passed in the route. This is based on the fact that an end user could end up directly on the page and such means that there is a good chance the info will not be available in the service or the localstorage - you could check if its there and if not make a request (smart service).

Comment: Yeah, I looked at defining each property of the employee object, but this would mean showing each of them in the url, which would be an issue, as I just want to show the id in the url

Comment: what about a simple service to cache the employee data?

Comment: I'll have to look into it, it's not something I'd know how to do

Comment: Well like i said in the update portion above - the best idea is just to make a new request to the server for the employee data.

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
        url: '/employees/employeeDetails?employee&id',
        templateUrl: 'views/employees/employeeDetails/employeeDetails.html',
        controller: 'employeeDetailsMainController',
        controllerAs: 'employeeDetailsMain',
        resolve: {
            lazyLoad: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/controllers/employees/employeeDetails/employeeDetailsMainController.js');
            }
        }
    });
```

use querystring params li these it will retain them after refresh.
for more info check doc [ui-router query params](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)

Comment: @nick.cook you cant pass object in querystring params like that.do one thing JSON.stringify($scope.employe) and then pass the string.

Comment: I know I need to pass in the employee.id property of the employee object in query, which is a string, but I did that you first suggested, and it cleared all employee data on state change, as I explained

Comment: @nick.cook that what i told you. Dont pass the employee as a object.make it a JSON string(JSON.stringify()).then give it to $state.go

Comment: Okay, I've done that, so I have this: $state.go('employees/employeeDetails', { employee: JSON.stringify($scope.employee) });

Comment: But that shows all properties of the object in the url, not just the id, and I can't access the properties in the DOM/HTML as $scope properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$location.search($location.search('employeeDetails', { employee: 
$scope.employee, id: $scope.employee.id });
```

and than get parameters that you need from `$stateParams` or if you use newest version `$transation$` or on `state` on `resolve`

```
selectedFromUrl: ($location) => {
                 'ngInject';

                 return $location.search().employeeDetails;
            },
```

If nothing help you can use `cache`

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't actually explained where any of this would go